# Is it wrong or uncommon to use whether when there isn't a second option?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

When there are two options, it's clear. You should use *whether*:

> He didn't know whether to go on Monday or Tuesday.

What about when there aren't two options? Example:

> He called to check whether she was okay.
>
> She didn't know whether to continue with the plan.

Note: what about this example?

> She didn't know the person who wrote the note, or whether this was a morbid
>   joke.

Comment: The first part of your sentence lacks a verb that connects "she" and "the person who wrote the note," I would expect something like **know** to be used .

Comment: All of these *whether*s are introducing an interrogative complement of a verb - they are doing the same job as *that* in he didn't know *that* she was coming, except that *that* is for declarative complements. In this use, it doesn't matter how many options there are. The situation where you need more than one option is where *whether* means *in the event that* - so *I'll go whether it is raining or (whether it is) sunny* is fine, but *I'll go whether it is raining* is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always another alternative, regardless of it being explicit or not.

> He called to check whether she was okay. (or not okay)
>
> She didn't know whether to continue with the plan. (or not continue the plan)

Comment: Yep, the second option is always there but sometimes unspoken (as it's usually a binary *do or do not* choice, rather than a choice between 2 different things like apples and bananas)

Comment: So it's okay to use *whether* instead of *if* in these sentences?

Comment: @alexchenco: all sentences you provided are OK to use.